# Find & replace regex in sublime text

Tags: php, regex, sublimetext3, sublimetext2

I am trying to search the string mysql_fetch_row with anything between parenthesis

mysql_fetch_row(anything)

and replace it with

anthing->fetch_row()

in sublime I have this search regex :

```
mysql_fetch_row\(([^()])*\)
```

and this in replace :

```
$1->fetch_row()
```

but $1 only catch the last character between the parenthesis

How can I catch the whole string between parenthesis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

move the `*` to before the `)`, so that multiple occurrences of the character class are stored in the capture group

```
mysql_fetch_row\(([^()]*)\)
```